# How can I ensure an object includes some specific fields using Partial<>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

I have a function with the following parameter:

```
const handleAccount = (
  account: Partial<IAccountDocument>,
  ...
) => { ... }
```

In no way can I change the interface for `IAccountDocument` to not require certain fields, i.e. I must use `Partial<>`. How can I make it so that `IAccountDocument` has specific fields included whilst also being allowed to be partially created?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html - either pick or omit the appropriate fields

Comment: What does it mean for IAccountDocument to have specific fields included while also being `Partial<IAccountDocument>`?

Comment: There is a field called `_id`, for example. If I don't set the parameter as `Partial<>`, it complains that it requires a document with the `_id` field; but if I **do** set the parameter to `Partial<>`, it allows documents without `_id`, which cannot happen.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Pick` utility type to choose some mandatory properties and combine it with `Partial<IAccountDocument>`.

```js
// Let's say that a and b must be mandatory properties
interface IAccountDocument {
  a: number 
  b: number
  c: number
  d: number
  e: number
}

const handleAccount = (
  account: Pick<IAccountDocument, "a" | "b"> & Partial<IAccountDocument>
) => {}


// valid
handleAccount({a: 123, b: 123, c: 123})

// not valid
handleAccount({c: 23})
```

Comment: But does this ensure that **both** `a` and `b` are required? As in my case, I'd need this.

Comment: yes, you get an error if you do not include `a` and `b`

Comment: Ah, I thought `Pick` worked as an *or*. Thanks, Tobias.

Comment: It actually doesn't work, at least in my case. With my partially-created object (`Partial<IAccountDocument>`), when I pass it into the `handleAccount()` I get `Property 'practice' is optional in type 'Partial<IPatientDocument>' but required in type 'Pick<IAccountDocument, "migrationData" | "practice" | "accessGroups">'.ts(2345)`. I have the `& Partial<IAccountDocument>`, too (even though I am not 100% on what this bit actually does).

Comment: If you have an object with the type `Partial<IAccountDocument>`  and pass it to the function, the information about which properties the object actually has is lost. You cannot pass objects of `Partial<IAccountDocument>` to the function as typescript has no way of knowing if all constraints are satisified

Comment: Hm, indeed. What it is I am trying to do then, I'm not sure it can be quite done. At least I learnt that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Typescript supports [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).

Borrowing from the answer by tobias-s:

```
// Let's say that a and b must be mandatory properties
type IAccountDocument {
  a: number 
  b: number
  c: number
  d: number
  e: number
}

type CustomPartialIAccountDocument = Partial<IAccountDocument> & {
  a: number 
  b: number
}

// valid
CustomPartialIAccountDocument ({a: 123, b: 123, c: 123})

// not valid
CustomPartialIAccountDocument ({c: 23})
```